# Self-hosting a dynamic dns service?

Tags: dns, bind, dynamic-dns

Is there a way to self-host a dynamic DNS service? I really like the flexibility of DynDNS et al, but I'd like to host my own dynamic DNS service so I can have better control and the ability to send my owned domains to the nameserver without having to pay a fee. Are FOSS implementations of dynamic DNS available, or is there a way to do this in BIND?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bind` v9 has support for dynamic updates:

```
zone "example.net" {
    type master;
    file "zones/example.net.db";

    update-policy local;

    auto-dnssec allow;
    key-directory "keys/example.net";
};
```

---

- You can use **`nsupdate`** to manage the zone locally,
- or call `nsupdate` **from a CGI script** (accessed by the client PC, like DynDNS updater),
- or use `nsupdate` remotely [**using TSIG**](http://www.ops.ietf.org/dns/dynupd/secure-ddns-howto.html).

  ```
  zone "example.net" {
      update-policy {
          grant <keyname> name <hostname> A AAAA TXT;
          //grant * self * A AAAA TXT;
      };
  };

  key <keyname> {
      algorithm HMAC-MD5;
      secret "<keydata>";
  };
  ```

  (docs: [`update-policy`](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/xfer.html#update-policy))
- Windows has native support DDNS using **GSS-TSIG**, which requires a working Kerberos setup (not necessarily Active Directory).
- In a local network, updates can be performed by either the DHCP client (ISC `dhclient`) or server (ISC `dhcpd`). This is also described in the [Secure dynamic DNS](http://www.ops.ietf.org/dns/dynupd/secure-ddns-howto.html) page.
- `bind` can [**automatically sign** dynamic zones](http://netlinxinc.com/netlinx-blog/45-dns/133-bind-970-part-4-automatic-zone-signing.html).